# What will the universe be made of at the heat death?

Tags: cosmology, entropy

Explain it to me like I'm a five year old.

It's the far distant future and the universe has finally come to its heat death. At this point, what will be left of the universe?

Will there perhaps only be photons by now, or would normal matter still exist?

Answer (score 1):

In the really long run the universe will consist of electrons, positrons, neutrinos and photons - each particle isolated from all other by so vast distances that they could as well be in a different universe.

Following [(Adams & Laughlin 1997)](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9701131), the first step towards this stage is proton decay at some point beyond $\sim 10^{32}$ years (it has never been observed, but is predicted by multiple physical theories). At this timescale the remaining matter - mostly inter-cluster gas, frozen brown dwarfs, white dwarfs and neutron stars - will start to vanish, their nucleons turning into leptons and photons. The process is slow, but in about 1000 times the age of the universe when this effect starts to bite all normal matter is gone.

Beyond this point there are only black holes beside the scattered particles. The black holes evaporate over long timescales, until in $10^{99}$ years or so even the heaviest have dissipated. Most of the emissions will be photons and neutrinos, with a few electron and positrons (in the last moments heavier particles will emerge, but then decay, the slowest due to proton decay).

At this point there are just unbound particles in an expanding universe, so far away that they will never interact.

Dark matter may remain to some small part (some of it falls into black holes due to gravitational radiation, but much of it escapes or is released as Hawking radiation). Similarly for gravitons if they exist.